# miktex, ucs, uni-global.def and empty unicode directory

Tags: fonts, miktex, unicode

I'm trying to compile a cv with LaTeX and the `europecv` class.
Compilation fails because a file named `uni-global.def` is missing.

After a Google search, I found that file should be into the `miktex/tex/latex/unicode/data` directory. However, that directory contains a `data` and a `contrib` folders, both empty.
What can I do to solve that error?

Below is the code i wrote.

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow,italian,logo,totpages,booktabs]{europecv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=1.27cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{microtype}

\ecvname{Albert Einistein}
\ecvnationality{Dutch}
\ecvemail{albert.einstein@relativitytheory.de}
\ecvgender{Maschio}

\begin{document}

\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo % prints the personal info, defined in the preamble

\end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an error in MiKteX packaging of `ucs`. I have made a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3565751&group_id=10783&atid=110783).
As workaround you could copy the files of [CTAN:macros/latex/contrib/ucs/data/](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ucs/data/) into the empty data directory (TDS:tex/latex/ucs/data/) and refresh the file name data base afterwards.

**Update:** The work around does not seem to work for the system distribution tree. But new TDS/texmf trees can be added using `MiKTeX Options->Roots->Add`. The files can be installed there (the directory structure `tex/latex/ucs/` should be kept) and then refresh of the file name data base should work. After MiKTeX has fixed the problem by an update, the additional tree should then be removed.

Comment: I copied the files into the tex/latex/ucs/data directory, then i went on "miktex options" and then onto the "general" tab. There i launched "Refresh FNDB" and the error persisted. Then i tried to reinstall and re-copy the data files but the error remained the same. Any idea?

Comment: @Alessandro: When you put files in the main tree of miktex you must refresh FNDB in admin mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've an administrator account; my OS is Win7Pro64. How to refresh FNDB in admin mode?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Docu for initexmf](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html) says `initexmf --admin --update-fndb`.

Comment: BTW: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Comment: It worked! I created a local folder and inside two nested folders "tex/latex". Then I extracted there the ucs.zip package downloaded from CTAN. After refreshing FNDB all worked fine. Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: For those who are only now looking at this answer, this issue seems to have been since fixed. After an update of `ucs` via MikTeX, everything works fine.